# Creating a Facebook Client - Choosing App Integration Type and OAuth Flow

Tags: facebook, oauth, client

I like to distribute content from within our Content Management System to several online channels like the website, twitter, linkedin and, last but not least, Facebook. Editors can create items and, eventually after a worfklow process, distriute them amongst the different channels.

Off course the website is no problem (it's still a CMS, isn't it). Twitter integration was rather simple. But now I like to create a connector with Facebook.

The approach is like this.

- Create a Facebook app: TheCMSFacebookConnector
- Give it permissions to write on a wall, create events, add photo
  collections, etc. A customer buys the CMS
- Within the CMS Manager there is an action to connect the
  TheCMSFacebookConnector app to the customers' (corporate) facebook
  account
- The OAuth dance is performed and the accesstoken en accesstoken secret are stored

From now we use the REST API to add content to the customer's corporate wall. This is exactly the way i did it for the Twitter integration.

But.........

### choosing the right integration type

When I create the Facebook app, the Facebook asks me to tell how the app integrates with Facebook. The integration types that seems to fit the best are Native iOS App or Native Android App. In fact the CMS acts as a Native App as well. **Has anyone a clue which App Integration type i have to choose?**. And are there other parameters that are important to set in a, maybe, different way?

### Choosing the authentication flow

A second question is about the OAuth dance. If we distribute the CMS amongst our customers, they host the CMS Manager environment in their DMZ with their own (mostly) corporate URL or, better, they host the CMS Server within the LAN and the Publication Server in the DMZ (we provide some tools to synchronize those servers)

When I do the OAuth dance, the CMS Manager (which is a webapplication) has is own URL. So in the definition of the app i cannot name an unique value for App Domains. From within the "OAuth dance""  code the redirect URL seems to have a connection with the App Domain and cannot be set in a dynamic way. **So is it true that for the "OAuth dance" the only valid method is the client-side authentication flow**?

Hope that someone can help me with, especially, the first question. Thanks in advance

E.

Answer (score 0):

> So is it true that for the "OAuth dance" the only valid method is the client-side authentication flow?

Not necessarily – you could always have an address from your app domain set as redirect_uri, and have that redirect to the CMS users web address afterwards (via a GET parameter in redirect_uri or something like that).